# Output not visible by writting into std::io::stdout()

Tags: debugging, rust, stdout

I want to use a struct which implement `std::io::Write` to output contents.
I use `std::io::stdout()` to test, but I cannot see the output contents, even though the buffer write is successful.

```rust
#[test]
fn show_test_2() {
    use std::io::Write;
    let mut buffer = std::io::stdout();
    match buffer.write(&"-----------------------".as_bytes()) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Buffer write success"),
        Err(_) => println!("Buffer write failed"),
    };
    println!("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    assert!(false);
}
```

By running `cargo test --lib`, the out put is:

```
test tests::show_test_2 ... FAILED

failures:

---- tests::show_test_2 stdout ----
Buffer write success
+++++++++++++++++++++++
thread 'tests::show_test_2' panicked at 'assertion failed: false', src\lib.rs:621:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

My question is:

1. Why is "-----------------------" not in tests::show_test_2 stdout?
2. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to want to use `std::io::stdout::write()` directly? What's wrong with using `println!`/`print!`? Although the question still stands of course why your code doesn't work.

Comment: To me it **does** print, but not in the test output, but directly to console without being caught by the test framework. Maybe `println!()`'s during `#[test]` don't print to the `std::io::stdout`, but to some internal buffer instead?

Comment: I want to test a function that accepts `std::io::stdout()` and other buffer, but I did not bother to implement such a type myself only for the sake of test.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't show your actual usecase, your example might be too minimal ...

Comment: Also, tests should be automated. How do you check for correctness? I think printing to an actual buffer and then checking correctness directly in the test would be more useful ... although of course this is pure speculation as I don't know your code. The code you show will only ever get the answer 'use `println()` instead'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90785
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12309 (from 2014!!)

The issue is that tests seem to redirect `print`/`println`, but **not** the actual `std::io::stdout()` function. This one still directly prints to the console, without being caught by the test.

The solution is pretty simple, though. Use `print!()`/`println!()` instead of `std::io::stdout().write()`.